# VAADIN Push not available with tomcat8 embedded

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, embedded-tomcat-8, vaadin-push

I created a simple test application:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;

public class Main {
  private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());
  private final static String mWorkingDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
  private static Tomcat tomcat = null;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    tomcat = new Tomcat();
    tomcat.setPort(8080);
    tomcat.setBaseDir(mWorkingDir);
    tomcat.getHost().setAppBase(mWorkingDir);
    tomcat.getHost().setAutoDeploy(true);
    tomcat.getHost().setDeployOnStartup(true);

    try {
      tomcat.start();
    } catch (LifecycleException e) {
      LOGGER.severe("Tomcat could not be started.");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    LOGGER.info("Tomcat started on " + tomcat.getHost());

    // Alternatively, you can specify a WAR file as last parameter in the following call e.g. "C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\app.war"    
    Context appContext = Main.getTomcat().addWebapp(Main.getTomcat().getHost(), "/app", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\Whys.war");
    LOGGER.info("Deployed " + appContext.getBaseName() + " as " + appContext.getBaseName());

    tomcat.getServer().await();
  }

  public static Tomcat getTomcat(){
      return tomcat;
  }
}
```

When I start this from eclipse, everything works fine, but when I export this to a runnable jar and run it I get this error :

> HTTP Status 500 - com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Push is not available. See previous log messages for more information.

Here is the entire call stack :

```
GRAVE: Failed to initialize Atmosphere Framework
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to createclass org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.newCometSupport(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:229)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolveWebSocket(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:288)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolve(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:274)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.autoDetectContainer(AtmosphereFramework.java:1591)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:717)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:614)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.PushRequestHandler.<init>(PushRequestHandler.java:121)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServletService.createRequestHandlers(VaadinServletService.java:82)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.init(VaadinService.java:186)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.createServletService(VaadinServlet.java:258)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.init(VaadinServlet.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:817)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.newCometSupport(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:225)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ServerContainer is null
        at org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport.<init>(JSR356AsyncSupport.java:43)
        ... 33 more

ao¹t 12, 2015 8:32:04 PM com.vaadin.server.VaadinServletService createRequestHandlers
AVERTISSEMENT: Error initializing Atmosphere. Push will not work.
com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: Atmosphere init failed
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.PushRequestHandler.<init>(PushRequestHandler.java:129)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServletService.createRequestHandlers(VaadinServletService.java:82)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.init(VaadinService.java:186)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.createServletService(VaadinServlet.java:258)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.init(VaadinServlet.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:817)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to createclass org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:741)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:614)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.PushRequestHandler.<init>(PushRequestHandler.java:121)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to createclass org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.newCometSupport(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:229)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolveWebSocket(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:288)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolve(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:274)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.autoDetectContainer(AtmosphereFramework.java:1591)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:717)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.newCometSupport(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:225)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ServerContainer is null
        at org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport.<init>(JSR356AsyncSupport.java:43)
        ... 33 more

ao¹t 12, 2015 8:33:08 PM com.vaadin.server.VaadinServletService ensurePushAvailable
AVERTISSEMENT:
=================================================================
Atmosphere could not be loaded. When using push with Vaadin, the
Atmosphere framework must be present on the classpath.
If using a dependency management system, please add a dependency
to vaadin-push.
If managing dependencies manually, please make sure Atmosphere
2.1.2.vaadin6 is included on the classpath.
Will fall back to using PushMode.DISABLED.
=================================================================
```

I tried to add javax.websocket-api-1.1.jar to libraries but nothing changed, still same error.

I don't know where is the problem, maybe I need to add something else, but at the moment I don't know what.

EDIT:

I don't use Maven/Gradle, for the tomcat8 embedded I downloaded [on tomcat8 website](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi) everything needed, and for the test application war I used one of my projects, working fine with Tomcat8 non-embedded.

Comment: Sorry for trivial question, but do you have properly added vaadin-push to your project (Maven, Gradle...)? If you use maven, you could give us also dependency tree.

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue is caused by any Jetty libraries included in classpath. They could be inside any other java jar - so you should analyse all dependencies of your application by some tool (even IDE integrated).

My suspicions is also based on [Vaadin Configuration tutorial](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Working+around+push+issues). Please look there - especially at [*Tomcat 8* section](https://vaadin.com/wiki?p_p_id=36&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=row-1&p_p_col_pos=1&p_p_col_count=3&_36_struts_action=%2Fwiki%2Fview&p_r_p_185834411_nodeName=vaadin.com+wiki&p_r_p_185834411_title=Configuring+push+for+your+environment#section-Configuring+push+for+your+environment-Tomcat+8+++Websockets).

Edit: When enabling Vaadin Push, please look also at official [wiki](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Enabling+server+push). There are described all changes which should be made in project (dependencies, UI annotation, web.xml).

Comment: I added every jars I have in eclipse project to the jar. Ans the application is working fine in tomcat8 installation. So push configuration is good :/

Comment: Ok, I understand. I reproduced your problem. My sample push application works fine on normal Tomcat 8. But when I used your code and tried to run it on embedded Tomcat it fails (but with some different exception). It was Atmosphere problem. I can't find any solution so far.